# O(1) set bit counting

Tags: python-3.x, bit-manipulation

I was looking into this set bit counting page: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-set-bits-in-an-integer/

The last algorithm **Mapping numbers with the bit** says: It simply maintains a Map(or array) of numbers to bits for a nibble. A Nibble contains 4 bits. So we need an array up to 15.

`int num_to_bits[16] = {0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4};`

Now we just need to get nibbles of given long/int/word etc recursively.

```
num_to_bits =[0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4];  

# Recursively get nibble of a given number  
# and map them in the array 
def countSetBitsRec(num): 
    nibble = 0; 
    if(0 == num): 
        return num_to_bits[0]; 

    # Find last nibble 
    nibble = num & 0xf; 

    # Use pre-stored values to find count 
    # in last nibble plus recursively add 
    # remaining nibbles. 

    return num_to_bits[nibble] + countSetBitsRec(num >> 4);  

num = 31
from timeit import default_timer as timer
t1 = timer()
print(countSetBitsRec(num))
t2 = timer()
print(t2-t1)
num = 421342356246244235625423523626342453143523624526434636546745745634523546346346346346344506546456909546540964596956306030963068359683578753068340634960340683463906835096835068309683486036830563596
t1 = timer()
print(countSetBitsRec(num))
t2 = timer()
print(t2-t1)

t1 = timer()
print(bin(num).count('1'))
t2 = timer()
print(t2-t1)
```

```
5
0.00013369599992074654
335
0.00015420899990203907
335
0.00011028399990209437
```

In the time-complexity section, it says it's O(1) in both time and memory. Even though the timing for both integers is close, I can't wrap my head around how this is O(1) as it's making recursive calls?

Comment: I'm sorry to say, geeksforgeeks is notoriously wrong or imprecise. This wouldn't be the first time. In this case, they cheat by first claiming that the length of an integer is variable (which in practice is not true due to machine architectures) and then later they assume its length to be a constant to get away with O(1). Time complexity is absolutely irrelevant at this particular level. At this level you only care about the effective performance, not the theoretical complexity.

Comment: yes, I see that now. I also thought it will be only O(1) for a 64-bit integer but they didn't mention it. It's really confusing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The memory complexity is shown `O(1)` based on the fact that it uses a fixed array (but there are many recursive calls, and that memory will not be O(1)).

The time complexity is not `O(1)`, each time `nibble = num & 0xf;` this gives an integer less than equal 15 (`0xf` is `15`, and the `&` operation makes sure the result is not greater than `15`). It then recursively uses those indices for a nibble.

We can calculate the steps for both numbers to compare; if the run-time is `O(1)`, the number of steps should be the same.

```
num_to_bits =[0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4];  

# Recursively get nibble of a given number  
# and map them in the array 

num_steps = 0
def countSetBitsRec(num): 
    global num_steps
    num_steps += 1
    nibble = 0; 
    if(0 == num): 
        return num_to_bits[0]; 

    # Find last nibble 
    nibble = num & 0xf; 

    # Use pre-stored values to find count 
    # in last nibble plus recursively add 
    # remaining nibbles. 

    return num_to_bits[nibble] + countSetBitsRec(num >> 4);  

num = 31
from timeit import default_timer as timer
t1 = timer()
print(countSetBitsRec(num))
print(f'num steps: {num_steps}')
t2 = timer()
print(t2-t1)
num = 421342356246244235625423523626342453143523624526434636546745745634523546346346346346344506546456909546540964596956306030963068359683578753068340634960340683463906835096835068309683486036830563596
global num_steps
num_steps = 0
t1 = timer()
print(countSetBitsRec(num))
print(f'num steps: {num_steps}')
t2 = timer()
print(t2-t1)
```

```
5
num steps: 3
0.00024106499995468766
335
num steps: 163
0.0012161659999492258
```

As you can see the number of steps directly depends on the integer size itself. For big integers, the number is proportional to the length and not `O(1)`.